# Recuperar Varbinary Asp

Tags: banco-de-dados, asp.net

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber como posso recuperar uma imagem salva em um banco de dados como varbinary para uma tag img no asp. O meu codigo está da seguinte forma:

```
<%
   dim objCmdI, RsImage, vsImage
   call AbreConexao()

   Set RsImage = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
   RsImage.Open "select Imagem from Usuario", 
   Conn

   vsImage = RsImage("Imagem")      
   Call FechaConexao()
%>
```

Esta é a tag que tenho

```
<img src="<%=response.Write(vsImage)%>" width="87" height="104" border="1">
```

O código do método AbreConexao() :

```
Sub AbreConexao
Call validaAcesso(trim(request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")))
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
Conn.Mode = 12
Conn.Open strConn
end sub
```

Obs: a chamada da conexão e a tag estão dentro da mesma Div.
Obs2: o código AbreConexao() está em outro documento, mas esta funcionando perfeitamente para outras chamadas no codigo, tenho certeza que o problema não é 
a conexão com o banco, mas sim como eu estou fazendo a requisição ao banco de dados.

Nunca trabalhei com código asp puro e peguei isso para fazer. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui recuperar imagem do banco da seguinte forma.
Criei um novo arquivo "MostrarImagem.asp", está pagina deve conter apenas um script que vai buscar a imagem no banco e mostrar na tela, o código desta pagina deve ser algo próximo a isso:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
 'Variável criada para receber um parâmetro para seleção da imagem
 Dim strID

 strID = request("userID")

 Response.Expires = 0
 Response.Buffer = TRUE
 Response.Clear
 'este campo deve ser ajustado de acordo com o formato da imagem que deseja buscar
 Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"

 Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

 cn.Open "Driver= 

 {SQLServer};Description=sqldemo;SERVER=IP_Do_Servidor;UID=Usuario_Banco;
  PWD=Senha_Banco;DATABASE=Nome_Banco"
 'Query que busca a imagem no banco
 Set rs = cn.Execute("select Imagem from Tabela_Imagem where Compo = " & 
 strID)
 Response.BinaryWrite rs("Cd_Foto")
 Response.End
 %>
```

Para chamar o script abra o arquivo que contem sua tag  e adicione o seguinte código:

```
<img src="MostrarImagem.asp?userID=Valor" border="1" height="200"  width="200" />
```

O parâmetro "userID" é opcional, serve para passar ao script um valor especifico para buscar a imagem no banco. Caso queira chamar direto basta utilizar:

```
<img src="MostrarImagem.asp" border="1" height="200"  width="200" />
```

Com o código descrito acima consegui resolver meu problema, lembrando que o campo que guarda a imagem no banco deve ser varbinary(MAX).